# how to concatenate string passing in an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm having trouble with an object that I need to pass a variable in so it's passing a string

```
this.context.updateCurrentValues({ "`${this.state.path}`": maskedvalue})
```

should be passed on like this:

```
this.context.updateCurrentValues({ "prices.2.price": maskedvalue})
```

I believe there is an error in the string concatenation, remembering that I need to pass an object to the function

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

To have the string you need, you don't want to use the double quote. But if you don't use the quotes, you will have an error. So you need to create your object step by step:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[`${this.state.path}`] = maskedvalue;
this.context.updateCurrentValues(myObject);
```

=============================

Old answer:

You don't need the double quotes:

```
this.context.updateCurrentValues({ `${this.state.path}`: maskedvalue})
```

Comment: syntax error, the crash app

`this.context.updateCurrentValues({ `${this.state.path}`: maskedvalue})`

Comment: Check the update, I think I better understood your problem

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `[]`. This should work:

```
this.context.updateCurrentValues({ ["prices.2.price"]: maskedvalue});
```